# How can I make a group optional which capturing a pattern and also capture the same group number?

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}\\s+[a-z|A-Z]{2}\\s+PLAIN\\sTEXT\\s+(.*?)\\(NS\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("2007 AL PLAIN TEXT ap2345 (NS)");
while (matcher.find()) 
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

I want it to work for `input1 = 2007 AL PLAIN TEXT ap2345 (NS)` (the above regex does work for this) but it fails for `input2 = "ap2345"`. I want to capture both these strings in the same group number which means I need to make the previous captures optional. How can I do that?

EDIT::: I want the same group number to work for both when the strings value is `2007 AL PLAIN TEXT ap2345 (NS)` OR `ap2345`

Comment: currently the `ap2345` bit is optional with `(.*?)`, should it really be optional?

Comment: @Pescis `.*?` is not optional `.*` but it is reluctant quantifier which will make regex find minimal match. Like in `ababab` regex `(ab)*` will match `ababab` but when we use `(ab)*?` it will match only `ab`.

Comment: @Phoenix I don't quite get your question. Are you trying to make `2007 AL PLAIN TEXT ` optional but without changing group numbers?

Comment: @Pshemo I didn't mean "optional", I meant it will always return an empty string. But it actually is optional too, try OPs code with input `2007 AL PLAIN TEXT (NS)`, it'll match. I think OP means that the `ap2345` should have the same group number with or without `2007 AL PLAIN TEXT` and `(NS)`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly so before I explain anything just check this regex

```
(\\d{4}\\s+[a-zA-Z]{2}\\s+PLAIN\\sTEXT\\s+)?(\\w+)(\\s+\\(NS\\))?
```

like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern
        .compile("(\\d{4}\\s+[a-zA-Z]{2}\\s+PLAIN\\sTEXT\\s+)?(\\w+)(\\s+\\(NS\\))?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("2007 AL PLAIN TEXT ap2345 (NS)");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

---

Example1 for `2007 AL PLAIN TEXT ap2345 (NS)` output -> `ap2345`

Example2 for `ap2345` output -> `ap2345`

---

This regex will try to store optional part `2007 AL PLAIN TEXT` in group **1**. If string wont contain this part group 1 will contain `null`. That is OK since we are interested only in part after it which will be stored in group **2**. I assumed that group 2 will contain only one word that is why I used `\\w+` (`\\w` match letter, digit, and `_`). If you want to accept more words try using `(.+?)(\\s+\\(NS\\)|$)` instead.

Comment: In both cases I want it to output ap2345

Comment: @Phoenix "ap2345" is stored in `matcher.group(3)` in both cases

Comment: Thanks Pshemo that worked. But Why is it group 3 and not group2 ? also why do we need to use \\w and not .*?

Comment: what if the string ap2345 contains ap/4325

Comment: @Phoenix You have few options. If you know all characters that should be caught in this group you can place it in character class like ([\\w/]+) or if you don't know try using "(.+?)(\\s+\\(NS\\)|$)" which will match everything that have "NS" or end of line ($) after it.